# SwiftUI pass Int value to the ViewModel

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I am trying to pass Int to the ViewModel, but it doesn't work. Value is still 0. There is no problem with Strings or Data objects, but Int, Double and others number values are still 0 value. I also tried this way:

> @Published var tankCapacity: Int?

but still same. How to resolve that? Use a string and convert to a given type?

```
AddVehicleView: 

import SwiftUI

struct AddVehicleView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: AddVehicleViewModel
@State private var selected = 0
@State private var showingAlert = false

init(viewModel: AddVehicleViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableView.appearance()
}

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        Text("Add new vehicle")
            .font(.system(size: 26, weight: .medium))
            .padding(.top, -30)
            .padding(.leading, 20)
        
        VStack {
            
            TextField("Brand/Model etc", text: $viewModel.name)
                .padding(.top, 10)
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            TextField("Capacity", value: $viewModel.tankCapacity, formatter: NumberFormatter()) // I am trying send int value from here
                .padding(.top, 30)
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Fuel type", selection: $viewModel.fuelType) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.fuels.count) {
                            Text(self.viewModel.fuels[$0]).tag($0)
                                .padding(.leading, 5)
                                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.trailing, 5)
            
            Button("Add") {
                if self.viewModel.name.isEmpty {
                    self.showingAlert = true
                }
                else {
                    self.viewModel.saveVehicle()
                    self.viewModel.name = ""
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .font(.system(size: 20, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, -350)
                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Warning!"), message: Text("Fill the fields"))
            }
        }
        Spacer()
        
    }
}
}
```

import Foundation

```
class AddVehicleViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var name = ""
@Published var tankCapacity = 0 // and here I am trying to get value.
@Published var fuelType = 0
@Published var fuels = ["Petrol", "Diesel"]

private let persistenceService: PersistenceServiceProtocol

init(persistenceService: PersistenceServiceProtocol) {
    self.persistenceService = persistenceService
}

func saveVehicle() {
    print("name: \(name)")
    print("tankCapacity: \(tankCapacity)")
    let vehicle = Vehicle(name: name,
                          tankCapacity: tankCapacity)
    
    do {
        try self.persistenceService.addVehicle(vehicle: vehicle)
    }
    catch {
        print("ADDVEHICLEMODEL saveVehicle Error")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where are you modifying tankCapacity value?

Comment: To the ViewModel. I edited the code. The View and ViewModel were stuck together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit the TextField (by pressing enter) first before calling `saveVehicle`.

If you instead to the following in your view model:

```
@Published var tankCapacityText = "" {
    didSet {
        tankCapacity = Int(tankCapacityText) ?? 0
    }
}
@Published var tankCapacity = 0
```

And in your view:

```
TextField("Capacity", text: $vm.tankCapacityText)
```

Then there is no need for the user to press enter.